# Creating an AlertDialog that will dynamically refresh based on operation

Tags: android

I am working on a dialog box that represents a syncing operation. So I have a variable number of records, when I choose the "sync" button on my app, it'll show something like the following:

"Syncing: record x of y"

where x is the current record and y is the  total. As the records successfully get synced the dialog box is refreshed to represent this.

Looking at the Android APIs it looks like creating an AlertDialog is the way to go, but I am not sure how I would write the code so that the AlertDialog instance is dynamically updating as it performs the sync operation.

Comment: An AsyncTask with a ProgressDialog should work well in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ProgressDialog. Start an AsyncTask, create the ProgressDialog in the onPreExecute() callback, update it in the onPublishProgress() callback (you must call publishProgress() from your doInBackground() method for thread safety reasons), and then dismiss it on the onPostExecute() callback.

The AsyncTask documentation has something pretty close to what you need to do: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a trick I saw once for centering the text in an `AlertDialog`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Title");
builder.setMessage("Message");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

// Must call show() prior to fetching text view
TextView messageView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

I bet if you changed the last line to

```
messageView.setText("Whatever you need");
```

it could work

Comment: user1456948's answer is much better

Answer (score 0):

Make a new Activity for the new dialog, add in Android manifest.

Create a new dialog, if it is null, cancel the dialog.
And catch new Intents onNewIntent to update the contents of the dialog.
Let me know if you have any questions..

```
public class NewDialog extends Activity {

private AlertDialog alertDialog;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Remove title bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    showNextDialog();
}

// Cancel the dialog if it is not null (i.e. contains message from previous dialog)
protected Dialog showNextDialog() {
        if (alertDialog != null) {
            alertDialog.cancel();
            alertDialog = null;
        }

// Build dialog with updated info
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(dialogTitle);
        builder.setMessage(dialogMessage);
        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        return alertDialog;
}

protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    showNextDialog();
    }

}
```